# Server-side rendering(express) with react router does not work

Tags: express, reactjs, redux, react-router

I am trying server-side rendering using node js, React, Redux and React-Router.

I followed react-router server-side tutorial but I am only getting root route, no matter what route I put. As you see in the routes.js, I have a route to detail.

I tried **path="detail"** as well 
and Link is like below

```
 <Link to="/detail"> Detail</Link>
```

When I click that link, it does not even give me error like "no matched route to /detail".

If you want to see all codes - [git repo](https://github.com/intelcoder/pokedex-korean/tree/serverSide)

Here is my code

**routes.js**

```
export default ([
    <Route path="/"  component={App}>
        <Route path="/detail" component={DetailView}/>
    </Route>
]);
```

**server.js**

```
    app.get('/*',(req,res)=>{
    match({ routes:routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).send(error.message)
        } else if (redirectLocation) {
            res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
        } else if (renderProps) {
            const store =  createStore(Reducers);
            const html = renderToString(
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
                </Provider>
            );
            res.status(200).send(renderFullPage(html, store));
        } else {
            res.status(404).send('Not found')
        }
    })
});
```

**renderFullPage** - this basically injects html from rederToString to html string

```
 <div id="app">${html}</div>
 <script>
    window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState)}
 </script>
```

**client.js(index.js)**

```
const history =createBrowserHistory();
match({ history, routes }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    ReactDom.render(
        <Provider store={store}  >
            <Router {...renderProps} />
        </Provider> , document.getElementById('app'))
});
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <PokemonContainer />
                </div>
            </div  >
        )
    };
}
```

Thank you for look into it and please give me any opinion about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the leading slash:

```
export default ([
    <Route path="/"  component={App}>
        <Route path="detail" component={DetailView}/>
    </Route>
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

No sure if that's the issue with routing but you have to pass store state to `renderFullPage` not the store itself. So it should be something like this:

```
} else if (renderProps) {
  const store =  createStore(Reducers);
  const initialState = store.getState()
  const html = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
    </Provider>
  );
  res.status(200).send(renderFullPage(html, initialState));
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. I am passing store into renderFullPage, which is initState

Comment: well, no :) checkout [redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html), which states that you should `pull the state out of store`